# C++ parser or static code analyzing

Tags: c++, parsing, static-analysis

I´m looking for a free software, tool, library or whatever to analyze C++ code.

As far as I know tools for 'static code analysis' like 'Cppcheck' are not helpful to me because I cannot define my own rules or output. A library which gives me an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of a C++ file would be the best, I guess.

My goal is to program a command line tool which generates an output containing something like:

```
Test.cpp:
The file contains 42 global Integers.
The Class Test has the following attributes:
  String name,
  Int size.
The Class Test contains the following global functions:
  void Test(),
  int getTestSize(),
  String renameTest(String newName).
```

Comment: I don't want ot sound trite but you can get all that simply by reading the header(s). Is there something specific that you're looking for here? What are you hoping to use this for?

Comment: Maybe you should implement your own analyzer.

Comment: What would be the difference to a complete C++ parser? In my opinion too complex for me. My goal is to write my own static code analyzer.

Comment: If you don't get a complete C++ parser with preprocessor and symbol table construction, you may not be able to find types, classes, variables, or determine for methods/members what their types are.  (That typedef T is defined in some namespace accessed by a messy path... you won't be able to find it).  You may not want the "complexity" of a full front end, but in that case you'd better be willing to give up on accuracy in your answer.  The latter usually turns out to be unsatisfying if applied to a complicated piece of software, and you don't need tools for simple pieces of software. YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

You can use clang and the existing analyzer or implement your own analyzer on top of the provided APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As David suggest Clang is a good choice, you have just to implement your own ASTConsumer , you can take as example the already  existing clang ASTConsumers like ASTPrinter or ASTDumpXML